# Jetpack Navigation: Hide label in toolbar

Tags: android, android-toolbar, android-jetpack, android-architecture-navigation

The new Jetpack Navigation uses the `label` attribute from the `navigation.xml` file to automatically update the title of the toolbar according to the destination fragment which is shown.

I do not want any title to be shown in one of my destination fragments so I can put a `SearchView` in this place instead.

I already tried `android:label="@null"` but the toolbar's title just falls back to the app's title. Calling `menu.clear()` in the `onCreateOptionsMenu()` callback also had no effect.

How can I remove the title from my toolbar menu entirely in a specific destination fragment only?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One solution would be to hide the action bar in your specific fragment and create a new `ActionBar` inside the fragment with your searchview etc. for it. Depending on whether it's a support or normal actionbar it would be something like this in the `onCreateView`:

```
val act: MainActivity = activity as MainActivity
    act.supportActionBar?.hide()
```

or just `activity?.actionBar?.hide()`

Obviously, you'd have to set up your own actionbar in the fragment layout as mentioned above. You could use something like the `com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout` with `androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar` inside, or any custom layout, be it from a library or yourself.

Comment: Thank you for this suggestion. I believe your solution should work but this way I am loosing the transition animation between the hamburger menu icon and the up button unfortunately!

Comment: In that case, you could also try accessing the action bar and changing the title to something empty? `actionBar?.title = ""`

Comment: This would work! Thank you very much! Still wondering why setting an empty title with the label attribute did not have the same effect...

Comment: I'm not really qualified to comment on this, but seems like the navigation library just defaults to the app title if you set it to empty. EDIT: one trick that's not really clean but you could also use is setting the label to " " (one space)

Comment: Yes it does! I just do not understand Google's design philosophy behind this.

Answer (score 3):

As an alternative, the android guidelines for [updating UI components with NavigationUI](https://developer.android.com/guide/navigation/navigation-ui) shows that you can use a `addOnDestinationChangedListener` like so:

```
navController.addOnDestinationChangedListener { _, _, _ ->
    toolbar.title = ""
}
```

This solution wouldn't require clearing the title in each individual fragment.

Answer (score -2):

Remove value in `android:label=""` in navigation.xml

```
    <fragment
    android:id="@+id/navigation_profile"
    android:name="com.example.app.profile.ProfileFragment"
    android:label=""
    tools:layout="@layout/profile_fragment" >
```

Comment: Not sure this answer adds anything to the discussion here